# ERROR: "You must have INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission" with AdMob

Tags: android, admob, android-studio

As the title states, I'm getting that particular error even though I'm quite confident that I've got the correct code in the Android Manifest.  I've already checked for the common errors like accidentally typing "users" instead of "uses" and making sure I use singular "permission".  Despite my best efforts, I still get this error.  I'm hoping that one of you can point out the thing I'm missing.

Here's the relevant portion of the Android Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
</activity>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And here's the entirety of my layout that's supposed to be displaying the test ads.  The relevant view is located near the very bottom.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <!-- Space reserved for buttons at top of screen -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddRevenue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/btnAddRevenue_Text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddExpense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/btnAddExpense_Text" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <!-- <TextView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/fillerText" /> -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <!-- Space reserved for ads -->
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adHome_bottomBanner"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adId_bottomBanner"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where did u add the admob id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of you added permissions inside `<application>`. You should write it inside `<manifest>` tag.

here is sample code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.stackdemo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.stackdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I *think* that this has worked, but I'm having nothing but frustration trying to get the ad to display.  By implementing your fix, the message has, indeed, disappeared, but so has the ad!  Now I just get nothing.  In the Logcat, I get an error that says the ad wants more space.  Says it wants <480, 75> and that is has <432, 46>.  That's complete BS because I've been giving it more and more space, changing weight values and removing other Views, and those "has" values haven't changed at all.  Mobile development is cool, but this has been quite frustrating.

Comment: Alright.  I finally got the ad to work.  Your solution was, indeed, the fix for the problem I was having initially.  Big thanks.

Comment: @Megacannon it would have been good if you had posted the reason why it wasn't displaying. Im having the same problem after including the permissions, but well, im gonna figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I had the same problem. but i have written like this in manifest and its worked for me. some kind of bug i think.

Hope it Helps!!